# Is there a numpy equivalent to pandas.apply?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a call which adds some random values to a pandas Series:

```
series = series.apply(lambda x: int(math.ceil(x + x * rand_value(range))))
```

For performance reasons I can't use the pandas.Series anymore and have to use numpy arrays instead.

Imagine my 1D-array data is stored in `a`, how would I transform the call from above to numpy? I read about `np.vectorize` but I don't understand how I would use this with my lambda and self-made function to call.
My Idea:

```
func = np.vectorize(lambda x: int(math.ceil(x + x * rand_value(range))))
a = func(a)
```

At first glance it looks like that both calls result in the same output, but I am not sure about that. Could you confirm this?
And is there a better way, than using `np.vectorize()`?

Edit: rand_value(range) is defined like that:

```
def rand_value(range):

    # create value between [-1; 1)
    rand = np.random.rand()*2.0 - 1.0; 

    rand = (rand * float(range)) / 100.0

    return rand
```

So I can't use `np.ceil`, because then my function will only get called once (?) and have always the same rand values, what I need, is that for every value in my array the function gets called.

Comment: numpy.apply_along_axis()

Comment: How are `rand_value` and `range` defined? How you would perform this operation in NumPy depends on that.

Comment: Have you tried simply doing `a = numpy.ceil(a + a * rand_value(range))`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get more than one random value by passing a shape to `np.random.rand()`. Once you have exactly as many random values as your input array, you can use plain numpy functions

```
import numpy as np

def rand_value(range, shape=None):
    if shape is None:
        shape = tuple()

    rand = np.random.rand(*shape) * 2.0 - 1.0
    rand = rand * range / 100.0
    return rand

data = np.arange(16)
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
rand_value(100.0, shape=data.shape)
# array([-0.0083601 ,  0.90346962, -0.70813122, -0.73467017,  0.87514163,
#        -0.29496392,  0.63828971, -0.10086984, -0.60248423,  0.26550601,
#        -0.17577315, -0.95178997,  0.64123385, -0.54732105,  0.28590572,
#         0.19727859])
np.ceil(data + data * rand_value(100.0, shape=data.shape)).astype(int)
# array([ 0,  1,  4,  6,  8,  4,  9,  3,  4, 17, 10, 18, 16, 12, 16, 30])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a randomized array using np.random.rand(). After that, you can apply to vectorize as pandas apply.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.rand(start_point, end_point) # generated array

np.vectorize(*your_function*)(*your_function_parameters*)
```

If you need an example please follow the function created by you

```
import numpy as np

def rand_value(range):

    # create value between [-1; 1)
    rand = np.random.rand()*2.0 - 1.0; 

    rand = (rand * float(range)) / 100.0

    return rand
```

Your function name is rand_value and your parameter is range. Now, we try to use vectorize with constant value as 5 or randint(low, high, size) random integer value, etc...

```
result_5 = np.vectorize(rand_value)(5)

result_rand = np.vectorize(rand_value)(np.random.randint(5,100,1))
```